# Using two mics and listening to one of them

Tags: microphone

I have two mics, One is for me and the other one is a music keyboard.
How can I mix the two into one while also being able to hear the keyboard through my headphones?

I've made it work with a virtual audio cable, but it adds a long delay on my keyboard and I can also hear myself.
VoiceMeter also worked nicely, but a lot of my programs broke their audio with it.

Edit for clarification:

I have a keyboard connected to my mic jack and a headset + mic to a usb port. I want to mix the keyboard mic and headset mic so I can use both together. But I also want to hear the keyboard mic through my speakers.

[image: Sorry I dont know terminology]

I downloaded [VBCable](https://vb-audio.com/Cable/) and set my sound controls like this:[image: vbcale setup]This works, but there is a long delay between when I play something on my keyboard and I can hear it. Plus I can hear my self talk as  well.

Comment: Welcome. // Can you please describe, best sketch, your setup in more details? E.g. which analog connections do you use? What do you mean by virtual cable? And so on. Thanks

Comment: Yes, i've edited it to explain it a bit better

Comment: Thanks. Just for my understanding: you connect the audio out of the keyboard to mic in of your computer? That would be unusual. // May I ask you, to add the product names of your kbd, both mics/headset, speaker, and computer, if you use it? // Still don't understand what differs both "mics". Thank you

Comment: My keyboard has its own speakers and a jackstick port for headphones, but I found a jack cable and connected it to my computers mic jack, yes it is strange. It's a yamaha psrf51 keyboard, but it only has a hole for power and one for headphones. My headphones / mic is a corsair hs80 usb wired headset.

Comment: And the mics was because i dont know what to call it, this is all so i can talk with friends online while playing music with them, so the "mic" is just the output or whatever discord records.

Comment: Slowly I start to understand your situation. Am I right, you installed iCUE on your computer? If so, which version? Do you have a link to its manual (pdf) for me?

Comment: For your use case: You want to play the kbx, hear in in your headphone, but do not want to hear your voice in your headphones?

Comment: I do not have iCUE.
And yes, but I also want to play the keyboard through my mic

Comment: Ok. As I understand it the headphones provide an analog signal (mic) and makes an analog signal audible (headphone). Close to or inside its USB-connector these are converted into or from a Digital Signal. Which means: You must have installed some kind of driver with your hs80. Which one was it? BTW, all these are details you could and should have added to your question via EDIT ...

Answer (score 0):

If you're using the older version of Virtual Audio Cable, in the Audio Repeater (MME) program you can set Total buffer to 125 instead of 500 and also increase Buffers from 12 to 16.  This will reduce the latency by 375 ms.  Sorry if this doesn't apply to the new VB Cable.  You would also have to set Wave in and Wave out appropriately.